# Is it possible to hide (or undefine) a typedef?

Tags: c++, mfc

To avoid confusion and possible errors, is it possible to hide or undefine a typedef.

I do a lot of c++ and java at the same time. In java, the boolean type is `boolean`, and in c++ it's `bool`. The problem is that somewhere in the windows c++ libraries, there is a : `typedef unsigned char boolean;` That means that, in my c++ code, I mistype the `bool` type as `boolean`, it will compile and it could cause unexpected error, because it's an unsigned char instead of a true `bool`.

So what can I do to hide or undefine the boolean typedef in c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible with a precompiler directive like the example below:

```
typedef int foo;
#define foo not_to_be_used

int main() {
  foo a = 1; // error: unknown type name 'not_to_be_used'
}
```

Basically, this way you cancel the typedef. The code above will issue an error if `foo` is used below the pre-compiler definition.

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d4ee6ab7a6a15ba)

Comment: Note to OP: Make sure you scope this carefully or you may find yourself breaking stuff.